# how to create a wrapper that will return the current PageData in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to create a wrapper class  that will let me use PageData as it was a strongly typed class.
i used this method before in asp.net using HttpContext.Current.Session to define all the items i can store in the session and all the manipulation of the session was done through that class.
example

```
namespace app.Web
{
    public static class Session
    {
        public string UserName
        {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value; }
        }
        ...........
    }
}
```

i want to know how to get the Pagedata in a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageData is only available within the page itself, not available anywhere else (like the controller).  The best way to do this is with extension methods.

Frederik Vig wrote a [blog post](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/12/extending-pagedata-with-some-cool-html-helpers/) showing how this might be done.

Example:

```
namespace PageData.Extensions
{
    public static partial class PageDataExtensions
    {
        public static string UserName(this PageData page)
        {
            return page["UserName"] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you can use the same method for Session as well, which might be cleaner than the method you propose.

Edit:

Based on your comments, there are several other options.

1. Create your data as a class and add that class as an extension.  i.e. Like above, but make it `PageData.Utils.UserName` this way it adds only a single item to the PageData intellisense and doesn't clutter it too much, and allows you to filter out the PageData methods from extension methods.
2. Create your static class just like you want to, but use methods instead of properties.

Example:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string UserName(IDictionary<object,dynamic> pageData) {
        return pageData["UserName"] as string;
    }
}
```

Then in your code just do this (assuming you have the proper @using statements in your view):

```
@Utils.UserName(PageData)
```

Comment: I removed my answer - you are right, I misanderstood the question.

Comment: i thinked about the idea, i liked it at first but then i changed my mind , the main problem is that the new proprities will be poluting the normal functions and proprities available on PageData Class. i prefer the static way because it seperates the items from the normal code. i know its bad to use static variables but i dont like the fact to instantinate the wraper each time i need to access it :)

Comment: @Karim - I don't understand what you mean by "polute the normal functions".  You're not.  Extension methods are their own class, and are in fact static.. no different than the other method you suggest.  It's just a little compiler sugar that makes it appear as if they are part of the extended class, even though it's not.  For example, you can't access protected or private or internal methods or data from the extension class.

Comment: @Karim - The extension method could otherwise be written as `PageDataExtensions(PageData).UserName`, and in fact you can call it either way.  I don't know about you, but i find it easier to write `PageData.UserName` than `PageDataExtensions(PageData).UserName`.

Comment: @Mystere Man:i am talking about something else. i am talking about intelisense. when u write PageData. the autocomple that will open will have all your defined proprities in the autocomplete dialog, and so it will be hard to see the normal functions because they will be in the middle of all your extention proprities. althought of course code wise your solution is much shorter and cleaner :)